# I want to get my textbox values from HTML document and post those when submit button is pressed using Json file in node JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

This is my JS file:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $('form').on('submit', function(){

        var email = $("form input[type=text][name=emails]").val();
        var todo = {email: email.val(),
                     pass:dat.val()};
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/project',
            data: todo,
            success: function(data){
              //do something with the data via front-end framework
              location.reload();
            }
          });

          return false;

      });

    });
```

This is my html document:-

```
<html>
    <head>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
            <script src="/assests/todo-list.js"></script>
        <body>
            <form>
                <div class="container">
                  <label><b>Email</b></label>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="emails" required>

                  <label><b>Password</b></label>
                  <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
                    <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

I want that when i click submit button value from both text boxes gets saved in my database(using Mlab),for that i am using a json file to fire post request to the server.

My main post request handler:-

```
app.post('/project',parser,function(req,res)
{

var register=Todo(req.body).save(function(err,data)
{
    if(err) throw err
    res.json(data);

});
});
```

EDIT:-

I removed my Javascript file and now i am directly posting the form using  and i am able to save my email address but not the password.

This is my main code now :-

```
app.post('/views/register',parser,function(req,res)
  {
     var data={
                email:req.body.emails,
                password:req.body.passcode
            };
            var send=Todo(data).save(function(err)
        {
            if(err) throw err
            res.render('login')
        })
        });
```

Comment: That doesn't look like JSON.

Comment: @walk Meaning ?

Comment: You wrote "This is my Json file" but it's javascript. JSON is for data.

Comment: yeah sorry i mistyped.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you're missing the `contentType` param.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  ...
```

then try again.

Comment: I tried but its not saving anything in the database.

Comment: Then it is vague. Try do sth to narrow down the problem first. Could be frontend or/and backend.

Answer (score 0):

I was not following the correct schema for the database when creating the object

```
var data={
                email:req.body.emails,
                password:req.body.passcode
            };
```

The property name was pass and i was using password that's why it was not inserting the password.

```
var data={
                email:req.body.emails,
                pass:req.body.passcode
            };
```